# Bash script to remove text from each line of a txt before a :

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop

I have written this script to remove text from each line before `:`:

```
#!/bin/bash
txt=test.txt
COUNT=$(cat $txt | wc -l)

while [ $COUNT -gt 0 ]; do
data=$(sed -n ${count}p $txt)
sed '$count \c
"${data#*:}"' $txt

let COUNT=COUNT-1
done
```

I think I have an issue with using variables in commands without spaces. Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do exactly? What does your input and desired output look like? [edit] your question to show us.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are over complicating it. To do this you just need `cut`:

```
cut -d':' -f2- file
```

- `-d` sets the field separator.
- `-f` indicates what fields to use. By saying `2-` we indicate "all from the 2nd one on".

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
hello:man i am here:or there
and:you are here
$ cut -d':' -f2- a
hello
man i am here:or there
you are here
```

---

#### Some comments regarding your code:

```
#!/bin/bash
txt=test.txt
COUNT=$(cat $txt | wc -l)     # you can directly say 'wc -l < "$txt"'

while [ $COUNT -gt 0 ]; do
data=$(sed -n ${count}p $txt) # you are using "count", not "COUNT"
sed '$count \c                # same here. And I don't know what
"${data#*:}"' $txt            # this sed is supposed to work like

let COUNT=COUNT-1             # you have to say let "COUNT=COUNT-1"
done
```

Also, it is good to indent the code, so that it shows like:

```
while ...
do
    ... things ...
done
```

All together, I would do:

```
#!/bin/bash

txt=a
count=$(wc -l < "$txt")

while (( count-- > 0 )); do
    data=$(sed -n "${count}p" "$txt")
    #sed '$COUNT \c "${data#*:}"' $txt # not using it
    echo "${data#*:}"
done
```

Since you are reading the file from the bottom and done some conditions around it, you could just drop it and just use `tac` to print the file on reverse:

```
while IFS= read -r data do
    echo "${data#*:}"
done < <(tac file)
```